# Server running 24/7 crashes router

Tags: .net, server, router

I have an unusual issue. I have a server with Windows 10 running 24/7, every 5-8 days it crashes my router in a way that shuts down the entire internet connection in the house through the router. The only way to solve the issue is to shut down the server and restart the router and when the connection returns can i turn the server back on.

- The server is being used as a .Net hosting server, i created DNS
  entries on unoeuro hosting website to point to my server. And in
  order to RDP my server, i access it using FTP port and in the router
  i re-route the FTP port to RDP port(Personal Reasons).
- I had a D-Link Router DIR-880L. I thought it was a cable issue,
  changed to a new cable(didn't help), tried new Ethernet Card and
  tried Wireless USB NetCard (didn't help either). So i thought it
  might be a Router issue.
- I bought a brand new Asus RT-AC88U(400$), same problem.

I am an IT-Engineer and i know my stuff, but now i am at a point where i am almost out of ideas.

Can anyone help?

Comment: This question is off topic for SO as it is not related to programming. Since you claim you are doing this at home the best SE site to ask the question would be [su].

Comment: Ok thanks for the info, i'll remember that next time.